# adding array value to a where clause

Tags: php, mysql

with this code.. I need to add $code variable to a sql query's where clause.

```
if ( isset( $_POST['code_search_submitted'])) {

        if ( isset( $_POST['searchCode']) && !empty( $_POST['searchText'])) {           


    $searchCode = $_POST['searchCode']; 
        $searchText = $_POST['searchText'];     

        echo $searchCode;
        echo '<br />';
        echo $searchText;
        //if (is_numeric( $searchText ) && (strlen($searchText) == 4)) {    

        $numbers = explode(",", $searchText);
        foreach($numbers as $number) {
            $numbers =  trim($number);


            if (ctype_digit($numbers) && (strlen($numbers) == 4)) { 

                $code = $numbers ;

            } else {

                echo 'Can not cantain string and more than 4 digists number';
            }

        }
}
}
```

this is my query...

```
SELECT 
    tcs.tutor_id AS tid, 
    t.qualification,
    GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT o.option_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS tutor_option, 
    timg.image_name AS img, 
    city_name AS city,
    d.district_name AS district
FROM tutor_category_subject as tcs
    INNER JOIN subject AS s ON tcs.subject_id = s.subject_id
    INNER JOIN tutors AS t ON tcs.tutor_id = t.tutor_id
    INNER JOIN address ON address.address_id = t.address_id
    INNER JOIN city ON city.city_id = address.city_id
    INNER JOIN district AS d ON d.district_id = city.district_id
    LEFT JOIN tutor_images AS timg ON timg.tutor_id = tcs.tutor_id AND timg.image_type = 'profile'
WHERE t.tutor_code = ------------
GROUP BY tcs.tutor_id;
```

$code variable have more member codes like this 2434,2345,5345,2354, etc... can anybody tell me how can I use this in my where clause?

Thank you...

Comment: I don't see any code related to database queries. What is your problem?

Comment: try if (ctype_digit($number) && (strlen($number) == 4)) {$code[]=$number;} S removed. then $string=implode(',', $code); and in sql WHERE code IN ($string)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( isset( $_POST['code_search_submitted'])) {

        if ( isset( $_POST['searchCode']) && !empty( $_POST['searchText'])) {           


    $searchCode = $_POST['searchCode']; 
        $searchText = $_POST['searchText'];     

        echo $searchCode;
        echo '<br />';
        echo $searchText;
        //if (is_numeric( $searchText ) && (strlen($searchText) == 4)) {    

        $numbers = explode(",", $searchText);

        $countmax=count($numbers)-1;

        foreach($numbers as $key=>$number) {
            $numbers =  trim($number);


            if (ctype_digit($numbers) && (strlen($numbers) == 4)) { 
                if($key==$countmax)
                {
                $code .= "t.tutor_code='".$number."'" ;
                }
                else
                {
                $code .= "t.tutor_code='".$number."' || " ;
                }

            } else {

                echo 'Can not cantain string and more than 4 digists number';
            }

        }
}
}


/////////////////////////////////////
//Query Updated
/////////////////////////////////


SELECT 
    tcs.tutor_id AS tid, 
    t.qualification,
    GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT o.option_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS tutor_option, 
    timg.image_name AS img, 
    city_name AS city,
    d.district_name AS district
FROM tutor_category_subject as tcs
    INNER JOIN subject AS s ON tcs.subject_id = s.subject_id
    INNER JOIN tutors AS t ON tcs.tutor_id = t.tutor_id
    INNER JOIN address ON address.address_id = t.address_id
    INNER JOIN city ON city.city_id = address.city_id
    INNER JOIN district AS d ON d.district_id = city.district_id
    LEFT JOIN tutor_images AS timg ON timg.tutor_id = tcs.tutor_id AND timg.image_type = 'profile'
WHERE 1=1 && ( $code ) 
GROUP BY tcs.tutor_id;
```

Comment: thanks.. what is doing this code '$countmax=count($numbers)-1;
'

Comment: its counting the numbers of items in array....for checking how many times the loop will work............ then we are going to concat $code .= "t.tutor_code='".$number."' || " ; and on last loop we will remove or (||) condition .i.e. $code .= "t.tutor_code='".$number."'" ;

Comment: We are just placing the string whatever we have formed above.............may be you will need to put certain conditions for this.......means if $code!="" then only it will concat with query

Comment: thanks..but I want to use $code value out of this main 'IF' condition. that mean my query is out of this loop.. then how I bring this $code value to my query?

Comment: Yes you can get the string $code after execution of the above if condition......then you can easily place this in your query....it should work....

Answer (score 0):

```
Updated code for query:

$query="SELECT 
    tcs.tutor_id AS tid, 
    t.qualification,
    GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT o.option_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS tutor_option, 
    timg.image_name AS img, 
    city_name AS city,
    d.district_name AS district
FROM tutor_category_subject as tcs
    INNER JOIN subject AS s ON tcs.subject_id = s.subject_id
    INNER JOIN tutors AS t ON tcs.tutor_id = t.tutor_id
    INNER JOIN address ON address.address_id = t.address_id
    INNER JOIN city ON city.city_id = address.city_id
    INNER JOIN district AS d ON d.district_id = city.district_id
    LEFT JOIN tutor_images AS timg ON timg.tutor_id = tcs.tutor_id AND timg.image_type = 'profile'
WHERE 1=1";
if($code!="")
{
$query.=" && ( $code ) ";
}
$query.="GROUP BY tcs.tutor_id";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_map` to convert/process each value and then combine them back and use `in` clause:

```
$numbers = explode(",", $searchText);
$parsed = array_map(function ($a) {
   if (ctype_digit($a) && (strlen($a) == 4)) { 
        return "'$a'" ;
    } else {
        echo 'Can not cantain string and more than 4 digists number';
    }
},
$numbers);

$numbers = '(' . preg_replace('/\,+/', ',',implode(',', $parsed)) . ')';
```

and then

```
SELECT 
    tcs.tutor_id AS tid, 
    t.qualification,
    GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT o.option_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS tutor_option, 
    timg.image_name AS img, 
    city_name AS city,
    d.district_name AS district
FROM tutor_category_subject as tcs
    INNER JOIN subject AS s ON tcs.subject_id = s.subject_id
    INNER JOIN tutors AS t ON tcs.tutor_id = t.tutor_id
    INNER JOIN address ON address.address_id = t.address_id
    INNER JOIN city ON city.city_id = address.city_id
    INNER JOIN district AS d ON d.district_id = city.district_id
    LEFT JOIN tutor_images AS timg ON timg.tutor_id = tcs.tutor_id AND timg.image_type = 'profile'
WHERE t.tutor_code IN $numbers
GROUP BY tcs.tutor_id;
```

Comment: what does actually do with this code '$numbers = '(' . preg_replace('/\,+/', ',',implode(',', $parsed)) . ')';'

Comment: @TharangaNuwanKumara it converts string `'1','2','3'` into `('1','2','2')` to be used with the `IN` clause in the SQL.